# how does collaboration in unity work?

Tags: unity, teamwork

i've been working on a 2d game for a bit now, almost all assets made but when ive tried to collaborate everything was quite glitched out, edits weren't saved, nothing was working at all. im not sure quite what the problem was because we were both on the latest version.

maybe i got to something wrong, or did something wrong im not sure. this was a few months ago now and ive been busy but i want to come back to this project. should i start over?

Comment: Can you describe what specific steps you were taking when you "tried to collaborate"? There might be a step you did wrong, but we'll have a hard time spotting it and telling you how to correct it if we have to guess at what you were actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you had messed up using collab at the first time. Collab is really simillar to git. Initiallize, update diff, merge conflicts... You'll get along to it.

I suggest you to reset the collab, as it have been a long time from last work. [This article](https://forum.unity.com/threads/collaborate-how-to-clear-collaborate-data-and-start-afresh.416554/) should help.

Also, take a look at the [manual of Unity Collaborate](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityCollaborate.html).